# Faster iteration over comments in issues retrieved by github3.py?

Tags: python, python-2.7, github, github-api

My objective is to get comments from issues in a Github repository which have been created in a particular timeframe. Currently I have to iterate over each issue in the repository (which are in thousands), and check each comment in the issue to see if they are within the required timeframe. This is very time consuming and can take several hours to complete.

I am wondering if there is a better way to get comments from every issue in the repository that are within a particular timeframe. I was trying the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
comments = repo.issues(None, 'all', 'desc', None, -1, None).comments(-1, 'updated', 'desc', <<mydatetimeobject>>)
```

Comment: Can you sort the comments first? It would be much easier to check if all the comments are within a time frame if you sort them in such a way that your timeframe is, for example, at the top of the list then you would only need to confirm a set number of comments and stop once you go through all the ones you’re looking for instead of the whole list.

Comment: The problem is that I have to iterate through each issue in the repository to get the list of comments in it. If I had a full list of comments without iterating over the issues that would be great, but not sure how to accomplish that.

Comment: Sorry I’m not family with github3.py, but there isn’t anyway to just get all the issues and/or their comments just as a bulk load?